# MySQL Query - select distinct showing wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

Im wondering if someone could help me.

I have hundreds of people uploading images to my site, basically each upload has its own row in the database with the data created, user id, images name etc etc etc.

What i want to do is display the last 3 users to upload images the problem being that if a user uploads  more pics, another row is added to the database with that users id so i can just show the last 3 rows.

I have the following statement, but it doesnt seem to be working properly

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM kicks GROUP BY uid ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3
```

I was wondering if someone could point me out where im going wrong.

Cheers

Sorry, i should have added sample data, ok

id | uid | created |

195 | 33 | 2012-03-06 12:32:54 
196 | 33 | 2012-03-06 12:35:23 
197 | 34 | 2012-03-06 13:09:31 
198 | 19 | 2012-03-08 10:37:21 
199 | 33 | 2012-03-09 21:04:04

Comment: DISTINCT applies to the whole row as expected. Can you explain more clearly about how the last 3 should be applied: the SQL is trivial but it depends what you really mean...

Comment: Is uid the user id or a unique key for kicks? What data do you want to be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM kicks ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3` is what you want.

Comment: Have you tried it? This is pretty straight forward and I'm 99% sure it works. Give us sample data to work with.

Comment: If you say it's not working can you tell us why? What are you really expecting the results to be?

Comment: I just created a test db and ran this query with your sample data and it works. uid 19 is the first row it returns by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM kicks WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM kicks ORDER BY created DESC
) LIMIT 3
```

or if your **id** column is auto_incremented, try to order by it:

```
SELECT * FROM kicks WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM kicks ORDER BY id DESC
) LIMIT 3
```

Comment: This doesnt work either ... does it matter that the 'created' field is a datetime?

Comment: No, it should not matter.Can you please post SHOW CREATE TABLE kicks ?

Answer (score 0):

Databases have a unique ID field, so a new row will have a new unique ID, meaning DISTINCT is redundant as every field is distinct if you're using SELECT *.

Why not try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM kicks 
ORDER BY created 
DESC LIMIT 3
```

Like I say, using * means every field is distinct.

e: You may need to provide more information on your database structure, that will help to understand how the fields need to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no problem with your query. The only problem is that when you group by users, you need to output the users personal greatest upload time with a function like MAX(). I got it working with similar data to yours.

Try something like lines of:

```
SELECT uid, MAX(created) as latest FROM kicks GROUP BY uid ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3
```

This will add the column "latest" to your query result: )

My version will allow you do display the rows unique ID, if you need that for some reason, but I think the accepted DISTINCT version is cleaner if not needed.